# Помогите решить задачу с массивом и вложеностями

Tags: javascript

**Нужно написать функцию которая принимет масив целих чисел и возвращает массив вложенних массивов где грубина вложености равна его значению, пример - [1, 2, 1, 3, 4] => [[1], [[2]], [1], [[[3]]], [[[[4]]]]]
Голову ломаю второй час, помогите пожалуста**

Comment: Цикл от данного числа до нуля. Нужна внешняя переменная, где будет храниться текущее значение, которое на каждом круге нужно будет взять и вложить в новый массив.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) для обработки элементов массива и построения нового массива.

[JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) чтобы нормально напечатать.

`nested` - простой цикл строящий вложенные массивы из одного элемента:

> ```
> n    nested(n)
> 0    0
> 1    [1]
> 2    [[2]]
> 3    [[[3]]]
> 4    [[[[4]]]]
> ```

```
const nested = n => {
    let a = n;
    for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        a = [a];
    }
    return a;
};

console.log(JSON.stringify([1, 2, 1, 3, 4].map(nested)));
```

> ```
> [[1],[[2]],[1],[[[3]]],[[[[4]]]]]
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Эту задачу можно решить, например, через рекурсию:

```js
const myFunc = (arr) => {
  if (arr.length === 0) return arr;
  return [
    [arr[0]], ...myFunc(arr.slice(1).map(v => [v]))
  ]
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(myFunc([1, 2, 1, 3, 4])))
```

Comment: на 2торой единице даёт неверный результат. ожидается "глубина вложенности равна его значению" ->`[[1], [[2]], [1], ...]`

Comment: Вы правы, не правильно понял задачу

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так:

```
function go(array) {
let result = [];
array.forEach( function(item) {
let arr = [item];
for( let j = 1; j < item; j++) {
arr = [arr];
}
result.push(arr);
} );  
return result;
}
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).